# Consuming JSON as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS project where the `POST` is not working. I have `@GET` URLs which work fine. Everything seems to work fine except this `@POST`.

```
@POST
@Path("/json/insert")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String postJSONInsert(
    @FormParam("instance") String instance,
    @FormParam("db") String table) {

    String json;
    EDPObject edp_obj = new EDPObject();

    try {

        json = edp_obj.insert("json", instance, table);

    } catch(Exception e) {

        edp_obj.endSession();
        json = handleJSONError(e);

    }

    return json;

}
```

Getting `500 not yet connected` in firebug when trying this on client:

```
$.ajax('http://127.0.0.1:8070/sixaxis/webapi/json/insert', {
    data: {
        db: '17:2',
        instance: 'shawn'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

since your jQuery is:

```
dataType:'json'
```

Update (thanks for the feedback):
Then the method at least should be:

```
@POST
@Path("/json/insert")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String postJSONInsert( Map<String,Object> params ){
   // Your business logic
}
```

Comment: You should add that in this case the `@FormParam`s are of no use. The JSON should be mapped to an object. JAXB can be used for this.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that among many other variations. The only thing that seems to work is if it returns a javax.ws.rs.core.Response object instead of a String.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a sample of your code for us to take a look?